# Phone automatically hangup when the call is picked up by receiver

Tags: calls

I am having problems when I call people. Every time I try to make a call to someone I can hear the ringback tone, but as soon as someone picks up the phone or their voice mail activates my phone will automatically hang itself up. I'm not sure what  should I do. I thought that factory resetting my phone would work but I don't want to risk losing all of my information that I have stored in my phone.

Is there any possible solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a firmware bug by your manufacturer and a update *could* be released if you report ASAP. However, if you are using a custom rom, then you should report the problem to the rom developer.